# I've written a jQuery plugin - how do I get it to run automatically?

Tags: jquery

As the title suggests I've written my jQuery plugin.

It adds visual feedback for password constraints to a password field.

At the moment, I have to manually call it

```
$("#password").addPasswordConstraints();
```

How can I make the plugin run simply by being included?

```
//plugin version 0.2
(function($) {
    $.fn.addPasswordConstraints = function() {
         //plugin code goes here.
        });
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically"? At page load? On click? Also don't you need to know which element to use that plugin on?

Comment: manually calling it is the way most plugins work. I don't suggest making it automagically run by simply including it as then it isn't very reuseable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to run it on page load for all password inputs, this should work.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.addPasswordConstraints = function() {
         //plugin code goes here.
        });
        return this;
    };
    // On document ready apply it to every password field.
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('input[type="password"]').addPasswordConstraints();
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are saying that you would like it to run automatically on all password fields, you could use that as a selector and always call it on page load:

```
$("input[type='password']").addPasswordConstraints();
```